# Postfix - Virtual Account - Can Send OK, But Not Receive "status=deferred (bounce or trace service failure)"

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

As the title states, I can send emails fine (including to external addresses like Google), but for some reason I cannot receive them. I have tried creating new email addresses and have the same problem, advice would be great chaps,

A typical error would be:

```
Jan 10 16:39:59 mail postfix/virtual[15452]: B5F2A408AED: to=<glenn@djrepayments.co.uk>, relay=virtual, delay=1023, delays=1023/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (bounce or trace service failure)
```

Regards

Glenn

Answer (score 1):

You need to grep the log for the actual error **before** the line you posted, like this:

```
egrep "(error|warning|fatal):"
```

It will indicate why the **bounce** or **trace** services failed.

Comment: Thank you! Your Answer was just what I needed to create `grep -B1 $QUEUE_ID /var/log/mail.log|egrep "(error|warning|fatal):"`